# How to make my app works on Smartwatch 2 when not connected to phone

Tags: bluetooth, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to develop an app to my Sony Smartwatch 2 that will work also when my watch is not connected via bluetooth. Currently, the app is grayed out (disabled) when it watch is not connected to the phone.

Any ideas? Pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you downloaded their sony sdk? and loaded their sample applications? That would be the first step.

Comment: Yep. I have wrote an app but my question is how to make the app work on the watch when the phone is not connected. Like the flash light app. Do you know about a sample that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running without a bluetooth connection to the phone is not currently possible for third party apps.  If I hear about any plans to open this up in the future will let you know.

Comment: OK. I guess it answers my question. Thanks!